# Check an array in C preprocessor (Function-like macro compile error)

Tags: c, arrays, struct, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to check that a parameter inside each struct in an array of structs is correct at compile time.  I would like the most readable solution that won't confuse those less familiar.

In any case, I currently can't get something that even compiles let alone works and isn't too cryptic.

I boiled it down to this as an example:

```
typedef struct int_struct
{
    int number;
} int_struct;

#define NUMBER_OF_VALUES
int_struct numbers[NUMBER_OF_VALUES] = 
{
    {.number = 0}, //Good, matches index
    {.number = 1}, //Good, matches index
    {.number = 4}  //Bad, doesn't match index
};


//Run static assert to make sure array is indexed using the correct state enum
#define _check_number_array() { \
    for (int i=0; i< NUMBER_OF_VALUES; i++) 
        _static_assert(i == numbers[i].number); \
}

static const uint8_t _array_is_valid_ = _check_number_array(); //Actually run our static check
```

Compiler:  error: expected expression before 'for'

Could you help me fix this error or suggest a way to check the initialization of an array with some condition?

Comment: A compound statement enclosed in parentheses may appear as an expression in GNU C, but not in Standard C

Comment: When defining array_is_valid, the example attempts to assign using the macro(), which gets replaced with your `for()` loop -- not a constant expression.  Try a runtime check instead, call the macro from a routine.